# What's the best gem to develop a Facebook Canvas/iFrame App (Rails 3.1.1, Ruby 1.9.2)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-canvas

I want to built a facebook canvas iFrame App. I tried to use facebooker but it does not work with rails 3. Can anybody suggest what gem I should use? If possible, please also provide a reference to a tutorial that can help me get started.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [fb_graph](https://github.com/nov/fb_graph) gem. The sample app code can be found at https://github.com/nov/fb_graph_sample.